How does the EM category for the multiset monad work?
I am working with the standard multiset monad defined on sets and functions and I want to start looking at algebras for the monad, the EM-category of the multiset monad.  I understand that this is commutative monoids.  The structure map makes sense when it is something like "average" but that means you have to be able to add up the set elements and multiply the set elements by $\mathbb{R}$, right?  Like if I have a distribution like this $50 \% \vert 1 \rangle + 50 \ \% \vert 2 \rangle$, then I can do arithmetic to get $0.5*1 + 0.5*2 = 3$.  But what if my underlying set is just a "categorical variable", so there is no notion of addition and multiplication.  Does this mean that there simply are no algebras for sets like this $\{ a, b \}$.  What is a structure map that works on sets like that?  If there is a total order, then you could return the probability for the max element, but what choice do I have if there is no structure on the set elements?

Well the algebra is the structure. An algebra for the free commutative monoid monad with carrier $A$ is a commutative monoid structure on $A$. Are you asking if algebras for the multiset monad have a known description in terms of some other structure?

You can consider the following multiset-algebra on ${a, b}$: send a multiset $X$ to $a$ if $a \in X$, otherwise $b$. (Note that a multiset on two elements is necessarily finite, so this is the same thing as a commutative monoid on ${a, b}$.)
